# Xcode continuous integration build failing because of system linker error?

Tags: xcode

I have a continuous integration build that is failing with the following error:

```
Errors:
"_CGColorGetComponents", referenced from:
"_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
"_CGContextAddLineToPoint", referenced from:
"_CGContextBeginPath", referenced from:
"_CGContextDrawLinearGradient", referenced from:
"_CGContextDrawTiledImage", referenced from:
"_CGContextMoveToPoint", referenced from:
"_CGContextRestoreGState", referenced from:
"_CGContextSaveGState", referenced from:
"_CGContextSetLineDash", referenced from:
"_CGContextSetLineWidth", referenced from:
"_CGContextSetShadowWithColor", referenced from:
"_CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor", referenced from:
"_CGContextStrokePath", referenced from:
"_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
"_CGGradientCreateWithColors", referenced from:
"_CGImageCreateWithImageInRect", referenced from:
"_CGImageRelease", referenced from:
"_CGPointZero", referenced from:
"_CGRectInset", referenced from:
"_CGRectIntegral", referenced from:
"_CGRectZero", referenced from:
"_CGSizeZero", referenced from:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This seems really strange as these are all system items that it says it can't find. However, the product is completed and available for download. I have other integration bots that are setup that run and complete successfully. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?